# TOMCAT showing java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException on updating web.xml

Tags: java, xml, maven, tomcat

Whenever I update web.xml it is giving me this error

> "An internal error occurred during: "Updating status for Tomcat v7.0
>   Server at localhost...". java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException"

I am using apache tomcat 7 with default configuration. This problem started when I was using tomcat on port 8080(home computer) and then i imported that project to my office computer with port 8080.
Other than this everything is same.

I have done below

1. re-created maven repository.
2. reconfigured server

Comment: Did you try to reload your webapp? Whenever you change a config or a source file you have to reload the webapp in tomcat.

Comment: yes, i reloaded the app, tried adding it again but no effect

Comment: Might be a configuration that loads a file with a machine-specific path. Try to see if it bugs in your code at all. It would be useful that you copy your complete stack trace to pastebin and link it.

Comment: ok, i found the problem
one by one I removed the maven dependencies and there was a c3p0 dependency that was causing the problem. after I removed that now it is working. Thanks for your time tough.

Answer (score 0):

I was having that problem and I solved it adding jax-rs api and works fine.

With error:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.24</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Added -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```