# Cannot run the maven project

Tags: java, svn

I have imported my project from svn and it is showing the following error:

> Could not publish to the server.
>   java.Lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Should i need to remove dependencies or what i can do?

While i am cleaning project it is getting as

> An internal error occurred during:
>         "Updating status for Tomcat v7.0 Server at local host...".
>          Java.Lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: That's "an error" but it doesn't show where the error came from. Post the full exception stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be a lot of reasons. Try to remove your server tomcat, and create one again. Maybe has been corrupted.

Regards!

Comment: I have installed new tomcat the same problem is getting.

Comment: I put you an example from other guay, that had the same issue like you.

Comment: Here is what he did: "ok, i found the problem one by one I removed the maven dependencies and there was a c3p0 dependency that was causing the problem. after I removed that now it is working. Thanks for your time tough. –" So, try the remove your dependencies and put again. Lets see what happen.

Comment: I put you the url. For more information. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747578/tomcat-showing-java-lang-indexoutofboundsexception-on-updating-web-xml

Comment: Thank you very much carlos.I am getting by removing dependencies in pom